# Is using Flask (Data Processing Server) along with Node.js (RESTful API) a good idea to serve data analytics server?

Tags: node.js, flask

After doing a lot of research on `Node.js` vs `Flask`, I came to the conclusion that when it comes to speed and performance, `Nodejs` does outperform `Flask`. On the other hand, I have already built an optimized application in pandas to perform data analysis.

Though I was planning to build my `REST API` using `Flask`, since my users are going to be big in numbers and gradually grow with time, I want to ensure that it doesn't compromise on performance.

I have built my frontend on `React JS` and now this frontend is going to make multiple API calls to my backend to get the data and perform `CRUD` operations. I am currently left with two options now:

1. Either rebuild my entire optimized data analysis architecture using pandas alternatives in Javascript like `Danfo.js` and host everything on `node`. This way I won't prefer to do as I don't have enough experience with data analytics packages in `javascript` and additionally, I have already done decent work optimizing my code in pandas.
2. To build my server in Flask that listens to `nodejs` requests locally and does all the data computation and returns the response to `node` which then sends the response to frontend. I am not sure how this architecture will perform when compared to only using `Flask` for both `RESTful API` and `backend processing server`.

Note that my frontend users are going to gradually increase with time and I want to ensure a great User experience.

Do you think that this combination has a better chance than using `Node` or `Flask` as a standalone system? Do you have any better alternative to all that I proposed? My aim is to ensure the best user experience and backend being able to handle multiple requests with the least wait time and not overloading the requests to the server.

Please note that I am not using `Flask` just as a `database` (so don't suggest me to replace it with some database) but more as a processing unit. Even when users aren't making any requests, some data modeling keeps happening within my flask framework via pandas (though it has nothing to do with Flask API Calls) in a parallel thread or processor you can say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to start with flask given that you have pandas highly optimized, but with a few additions besides vanilla flask. A few things to consider:

- track influx requests volume
- time for how long does it takes for each request to process with pandas
- to introduce distributed task worker early on (eg. celery and etc.) especially if the processing should be something running asynchronously and out of the request and response cycle
- cloud functions (eg. GCP or equivalent on AWS) because it seems like you want something that can process as per request, and cloud function supports burst of requests + charge as you use

The list can go on and on, but hopefully it gets you started with less doubts. Cheers!

Comment: I thought of using cloud functions, the only problem with that is to hit my local storage I have to anyway ping my compute engine. Just out of curiosity have you used cloud functions for storage as well?

Comment: if you are using GCP, i believe there is no storage within the cloud function instance but you can write a simple script to store the information to your cloud bucket / storage.

Comment: Hmm i see... Do you have any resource or a quick start guide to point utilising cloud buckets with cloud functions?

Comment: i have been using coursera to learn GCP, which i think is quite useful. also there are a few books published by orielly and packt proved to be usefull.